# How can mount freebsd disk partition with read and write permission in deban?

Tags: permissions, mount, freebsd, ufs

My freebsd installed on /dev/sdb2,it can mount with read permission:

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/freebsd
sudo mount -r  -t ufs -o ufstype=ufs2 /dev/sdb2  /mnt/freebsd
```

How can mount it with read and write permission then?

```
sudo mount -rw  -t ufs -o ufstype=ufs2 /dev/sdb2  /mnt/freebsd
mount: /mnt/freebsd: /dev/sdb2 is write-protected but explicit read-write mode requested.
```

Comment: check your `dmesg` after mount.

Comment: ufs: ufs was compiled with read-only support, can't be mounted as read-write